# TrueVFS net.java.truevfs.access.TFile.TFile.rm() is unable to remove the file

Tags: truezip, truevfs

TrueVFS is unable to remove the file after unmount and throws the following exception.

> ```
>     java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException: tar:file:/D:/tmp/0554de32-5a95-4b58-a05d-d12effa68abc.tar!/
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.ArchiveFileSystem.unlink(ArchiveFileSystem.scala:326)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.BasicArchiveController.unlink(BasicArchiveController.scala:222)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.DefaultManager$BackController.net$java$truevfs$kernel$impl$CacheController$$super$unlink(DefaultManager.scala:39)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.CacheController$class.unlink(CacheController.scala:105)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.DefaultManager$BackController.net$java$truevfs$kernel$impl$SyncController$$super$unlink(DefaultManager.scala:39)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.SyncController$$anonfun$unlink$1.apply$mcV$sp(SyncController.scala:100)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.SyncController$$anonfun$unlink$1.apply(SyncController.scala:98)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.SyncController$$anonfun$unlink$1.apply(SyncController.scala:98)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.SyncController$class.net$java$truevfs$kernel$impl$SyncController$$apply(SyncController.scala:119)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.SyncController$class.unlink(SyncController.scala:98)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.DefaultManager$BackController.net$java$truevfs$kernel$impl$LockController$$super$unlink(DefaultManager.scala:39)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.LockController$$anonfun$unlink$1.apply$mcV$sp(LockController.scala:92)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.LockController$$anonfun$unlink$1.apply(LockController.scala:92)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.LockController$$anonfun$unlink$1.apply(LockController.scala:92)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.LockingStrategy.apply(LockingStrategy.scala:84)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.LockController$class.unlink(LockController.scala:92)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.DefaultManager$BackController.unlink(DefaultManager.scala:39)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.ArchiveControllerAdapter.unlink(ArchiveControllerAdapter.scala:35)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.spec.FsDecoratingController.unlink(FsDecoratingController.java:111)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.FalsePositiveArchiveController$$anonfun$1.apply(FalsePositiveArchiveController.scala:132)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.FalsePositiveArchiveController$$anonfun$1.apply(FalsePositiveArchiveController.scala:131)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.FalsePositiveArchiveController$TryChild$.apply(FalsePositiveArchiveController.scala:195)
>     at net.java.truevfs.kernel.impl.FalsePositiveArchiveController.unlink(FalsePositiveArchiveController.scala:143)
>     at net.java.truevfs.access.TFile.rm(TFile.java:2216)
>     at net.java.truevfs.access.TFile.rm(TFile.java:2195
> ```

The tar file is successfully created, so no issues with that.

Here is what I am doing.

1. Configure the True VFS

   TConfig config = TConfig.current();
   config.setArchiveDetector(new TArchiveDetector("tar", new TarDriver()));
2. Create the tar
3. Unmount the tar

   TVFS.umount(tarFile);

   convert into bytes and send it.
4. Remove the file

   tarFile.rm()

I also tried tarFile.rm_r() and plain java.io.File.delete(). But none of them are working.

Can some one please advice me what went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TrueVFS abstracts the TAR file into a virtual directory, so you can only remove it if it's empty. To recursively remove a (virtual) directory with all its members, just call `TFile.rm_r()`. You said you tried that, but maybe there was a side effect of your previous attempts, so I suggest to repeat it and see how far it gets you.

Comment: Thanks Christian. I tried TFile.rm_r(). It works now. I did a bit of re-factoring. Still not sure why it didn't worked y'day. In fact I used this api before, back in 2007 beginning when I was working for HSBC http://devjav.blogspot.com/2007/03/jzip-zip-utility-written-in-java.html.